Updating multiple nested Objects in DRF
I have three linked models with many To many field relationship.
I have no ideia how can i update all instances at once.
I would like create three separated serializers, that could update the three instances.
class PlannedChargePriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChargePrice
        fields = ['id', 'start', 'end', 'price']

class PlannedChargeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = PlannedChargePriceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Charge
        fields = ['id', 'type', 'qtd', 'status', 'prices']

class PlannedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    charges = PlannedChargeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Planned
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'date', 'charges']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        charges_data = validated_data.pop('charges')
        planned = Planned.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for charge_data in charges_data:
            charge_prices_data = charge_data.pop('prices')
            charge = Charge.objects.create(planned=planned, **charge_data)

            for charge_price_data in charge_prices_data:
                ChargePrice.objects.create(charge=charge, **charge_price_data)

        return planned

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # No idea how update multiple nested objects
        return instance


Please, append models.py to the question.

In the documentation from Django REST Framework it states:

By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.

In short, there's no out-of-the-box solution, you'll have to write the serializer yourself.

you will need to override the update method update() in your main serializer yo will iterate through the nested serializers, updating or creating new instances has necessary.
   def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    updated_charges = validated_data.pop('charges', [])

    if updated_charges:
        existing_charges = {charge.id: charge for charge in instance.charges.all()}

        for charge_info in updated_charges:
            charge_id = charge_info.get('id')
            charge_prices_info = charge_info.pop('prices', [])

            if charge_id in existing_charges:
                current_charge = existing_charges[charge_id]
                for field, value in charge_info.items():
                    setattr(current_charge, field, value)
                current_charge.save()

                if charge_prices_info:
                    existing_prices = {price.id: price for price in current_charge.prices.all()}

                    for price_info in charge_prices_info:
                        price_id = price_info.get('id')

                        if price_id in existing_prices:
                            current_price = existing_prices[price_id]
                            for field, value in price_info.items():
                                setattr(current_price, field, value)
                            current_price.save()
                        else:
                            ChargePrice.objects.create(charge=current_charge, **price_info)
            else:
                new_charge = Charge.objects.create(planned=instance, **charge_info)

                if charge_prices_info:
                    for price_info in charge_prices_info:
                        ChargePrice.objects.create(charge=new_charge, **price_info)

    return instance

